# Right way to implement member functions

Tags: c++, linker

I have three files -- main, a header and its 'implementation':

```
// main.cpp
#include "word_indexer.h"

int main() {
    WordIndexer wd;
    cout << wd.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}

// word_indexer.h
class WordIndexer {
public:
    int size() const;  // declaring a function
};


// word_indexer.cpp
class WordIndexer {
public:
    int size() const {return 0;}
};
```

Building with `g++ -o main main.cpp word_indexer.cpp` yields

> undefined reference to 'WordIndexer::size() const'

Replacing the implementation with

```
// updated word_indexer.cpp
class WordIndexer {
public:
    int size() const;
};

int WordIndexer::size() const {return 0;}
```

fixes the problem.
I cannot figure out the difference between these `word_indexer.cpp` and its updated versions, they seem to be identical.

Why does the first variant have linking problems?

Comment: Btw: You header should have an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to repeat the definition of the class in its implementation file. Just have it include the header the class is defined in and then define the member functions in the implementation file like:

```
// word_indexer.cpp
#include "word_indexer.h"
int WordIndexer::size() const {return 0;}
```

As for why the first variant did not work: Member functions defined in a class are implicitly `inline`. Thus, their definitions must be present in every translation unit that uses them. This is why this works if you define the member in the class in the header file, but not if you only have the inline definition in another `.cpp` file.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to implement class in this inline style without making class methods really inline (in compiler sense of the word)? My goal is to keep .h / .cpp layout while avoid `WordIndexer::` prefix.

Comment: @DimG No, and you *really* should not put the class definition in the .cpp file. Either define the function in the class in the header or do the prefixing business in the .cpp. Also the prefixing is not really that bad if you get a editor with a good autocomplete feature (which I would highly recommend).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it's usually done for classes.

Header (`word_indexer.h`):

```
// declare the class and all its methods, member variables, etc.
class WordIndexer {
public:
    int size() const;  // declaring a function, but not its implementation
};
```

Implementation (`word_indexer.cpp`):

```
// the implementation basically takes the header "skeleton" and fleshes it out;
// to do that, of course, we need the skeleton first
#include "word_indexer.h"

// we don't need to say "class WordIndexer {}" or anything like that,
// because that's already been done in the header we included

// implement the method
int WordIndexer::size() const {return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `word_indexer.cpp` you should have written something like:

```
int WordIndexer::size() const {return 0;}
```

That's the actual definition syntax.

And instead of redeclaring `WordIndexer` in the translation unit, just `#include "word_indexer.h"`.